# My ifstream doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, system-calls

This is a main file that I am using to test methods before I implement them.  I am trying to get the list of all files in a directory, write them to a txt file (It works fine until here), then read the file names from that text file.

```
using namespace std;

string sysCall = "", location = "~/Documents/filenames.txt";
string temp = "";
sysCall = "ls / > "+location;
system(sysCall.c_str());

ifstream allfiles(location.c_str());
allfiles.good();
getline(allfiles, temp);
cout<<temp<<endl;  //At this point, the value of temp is equal to ""

return -1;
```

After the program runs, no text has been outputted.  From what I've read in other peoples' questions, this should work (but obviously doesn't).  What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: allfiles.good() returns false, but I don't understand why it would return that...

Comment: Does the file `~/Documents/filenames.txt` contain the expected list of files after you run the program, i.e. is it only the reading that goes wrong?

Comment: Also, calling `allfiles.good()` by itself like that doesn't do anything. You should **check** whether `allfiles.good()` returns `true` or `false`. If it's `false`, the file wasn't opened correctly and there is a problem with your filename.

Comment: yes, the filenames.txt file contains a list of the expected filenames.  It is only reading them that is a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ifstream allfiles("~/Documents/filenames.txt");` doesn't do what you think it does. The tilde `~` character is not part of the filename -- it is a special character interpreted by some shells. You need the entire path, with no `~` or `$` characters in it.

Try setting `location` to `"/tmp/filenames.txt"`, or just `"filenames.txt"`.

Also, if [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) is available to you, you could use a `directory_iterator` instead of invoking `/bin/ls`.

Comment: Indeed. He should probably change it to `/home/userame/Documents/filenames.txt`

Answer (score 4):

I'll bet the `system()` call expands the `~` in the filename to your home directory (e.g. `/home/mrswmmr`), but `ifstream` does not. Replace the `~` with the full path to your home directory and it should work.

Comment: This is what happens on my system.

Answer (score 0):

It has no guarantee to work because `system` gives no guarantee.

Comment: The system call works, and it writes the text file just fine.  It's the ifstream and getline that aren't working

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly is "gives no guarantee" supposed to mean? If the `system()` call returns 0, does that not guarantee that the command has been executed and exited with a return code of 0?

Comment: @HighCommander4 The C++ Standard defers to C for the specification of `system`. Unfortunately I do not have access to a copy of the C standard. However, from the C99 draft (and I have no reason to believe this changed from C89): "information may be returned from the called program in two ways: through the implementation-defined return value [...]". So an implementation that always returns 42 when the argument is non-null is conforming. (The other way mentioned in the snippet is about files.)

Comment: I do not have a quote as for the argument passed to `system` because the guarantees are somewhat scattered. But a program is able to query if `system` behaves well: if `system(0)` is true then that means `system` will understand commands. So that is the one guarantee.